# Unable to access nested JSON elements in Python's request reponse

Tags: python, json, parsing

I've been trying to call an API GET request to get a list of countries from an online sim provider. I'm trying to get the list of all the countries and to access certains elements from it.

The result of the request is such as :

```
{
   "afghanistan": {
      "iso": {
         "af": 1
      },
      "prefix": {
         "+93": 1
      },
      "text_en": "Afghanistan",
      "text_ru": "Афганистан",
      [...]
   "albania": {
      [...]
}
```

My issue that I can't find a proper way to loop over the array (afghanistan, albania, [...]) and to access the `text_en` key.

Out of everything that I have tried, this is (not working) what I think should work, according to examples / people's issues I found online :

```
countries = requests.get("(api_link)").json()

for country in countries:
    print(country['text_en'])
```

giving me the following error : `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

As my array is not named like most of the examples I found online (the root of the array is named for example `list` and the code look like :

```
for country in countries['list']:
    print(country['list']['text_en'])
```

Why can't I do it like my first example ? The thing I thought about is that my JSON isn't properly loaded (hence the `TypeError: string indices must be integers`), the way I loop over the array (for i in X or by using a JSON function?) or maybe because of the "issue" mentionned above (not having a "root" array name) ?

Comment: I've just seen Grismar's answer and it fits my needs. Do you have any example of what it would look like with a dictionary object, if it's not like Grismar's for loop changed to ```for key, data``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countries` is a dictionary. `for country in countries` therefore loops over the keys in the dictionary, and if you try `country['text_en']`, you're trying to index the first key (a string) with another string, which won't work.

Something like `countries['afghanistan']['text_en']` would evaluate to `'Afghanistan'`.

To print all of them:

```
for key, data in countries.items():
    print(key, data['text_en'])
```

This works because it loops over items, which yields tuples of key and value from the dictionary.

Another approach, closer to what you expected:

```
for key in countries:
    print(key, countries[key]['text_en'])
```

That may be a bit less efficient, because you need to look up every element using its key one at a time, while the first loop accesses all of them in order, but code that's readable is worth something too - at the very least, perhaps it helps to see how the dictionary works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked fine with the first way and I think I understand it better. From what I understand ```items()``` returns a tuple? if ```key``` and ```data``` which gives me the possibility to actually get the next object and not string (I tried printing its type after writing my question and found it was a string, so obviously wouldn't work like intended).

Comment: Almost - `items()` returns an iterator that allows you to iterate over the contents of a dictionary *as tuples*, so one `key, data` tuple at a time. And in your case, `data` itself then is another dictionary, which contains the `text_en` key.

Comment: Oh okay, if I'd like to go further down should I use ```key.items()``` to access its content or is everything "unlocked", or like "added recursively" to the dictionary ?

Edit : I just tried it out and if I know the actual content I can simply use ```print(data['iso']['af'])``` (in my case), or loop over with new key and data tuple to go further down.

Comment: I'd recommend reading a bit more about dictionaries, because I can't go down the rabbit hole of explaining it all one question at a time, but a `dict` is simply a pairing of keys and values. You can set or get a value with its key like `d[key]`. If that value is another `dict`, the same applies, you can get to *its* values with `d[key1][key2]`. You typically only use `items()` (on a `dict`, not on a key) to loop over pairs of key and value in one go. There's no "recursively", since you just get a `dict` if a value is a `dict`, which does indeed already contain all its contents.